# Epoch 0 to Date conversion using momnet.js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, epoch

I need to convert my epoch date to a Date object. I did this using the following code.

```
let abc = moment(maintenance.actualEndDate * 1000).format('DD/MMM/YYYY hh:mm');
```

but there is a high chance to `0` as the value for '`maintenance.actualEndDate'`.
in this case the transalated date is showing the value as '01/01/1970 12:00'.

I actually need as an empty string in variable `abc` if the `maintenance.actualEndDate` is `0`

I'm working on angular 4,  is there any optimal solution to this?

Comment: `let abc = maintenance.actualEndDate===0 ? '' : moment(maintenance.actualEndDate * 1000).format('DD/MMM/YYYY hh:mm')` ? Just basic JS, nothing specific to momentjs or angular

Comment: @HuguesMoreau - you can put that as an answer.

Comment: @Akash - you should also prefer `moment.unix(...)` instead of multiplying by 1000, and also you're seeing 12 because you've got `hh` - you should use `HH` for a 24 hour clock (or just `H` if you don't want leading zeros) - or also include `A` to get AM/PM on a 12-hour clock.

Comment: Oh - and terminology: You don't have an "epoch".  You have a "Unix Timestamp", which is based on an epoch.  An epoch is a fixed point in time; the start of something. The Unix Epoch is a fixed point in time at `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Comment: Done, I was half expecting OP to come up with a hidden requirement (what's an "optimal solution"?)... But if it's useful, OK. Also, borrowing your suggestion for `moment.unix()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is converting non-zero timestamps to a formatted date, and zero timestamps as empty string, a dedicated function would be nice:

```
function formatTimestamp(secondsSinceEpoch) {
    return secondsSinceEpoch===0 ? '' : moment.unix(secondsSinceEpoch).format('DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm');
}
//...
let abc = formatTimestamp(maintenance.actualEndDate);
```

(But this has nothing specific to angular)